# Confused with gamete sorting problem

Tags: human-biology, genetics, homework, human-genetics

A man has the genotype AaBbCc, in other words he is heterozygous in three uncoupled loci on three different chromosomes. A, B and C are the dominant alleles while a, b and c are the recessive alleles.

**1. How many gametes can he form?**

The answer is 8 and I can see how you derive that by just manually writing each and every one down but what is the mathematical method to derive this? I tried permutations but none I came up with worked.

**2. He has a child with a woman of the same genotype (AaBbCc) how many different genotypes can the offspring have?**

Here the answer is 27. I'm not sure how they came to this conclusion either?

**3. What is the probability that the offspring has the genotype AaBbCc?**

This is about the time I start flipping tables because it seems to me that it's 1 out of 27. There are 27 different genotypes and this is ONE of them?!

But the answer is 1/8 as there's a 50% chance of Aa, Bb and Cc when mixing apparently so it becomes 1/2*1/2*1/2. Why isn't it just 1 of the possible genotypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since there are 2 alleles of each gene and 3 different genes, 2EE3 = 8? Let's test this by making a table, for 1 gene there are two different kinds of gametes, so 2EE1 = 2, for 2 genes there are 4 different kinds of gametes (AB, Ab, aB, ab) so 2EE2 = 4, and you already did the calculation yourself for 3 genes, and 2EE3 =  8.

Why don't you try working it out yourself for 4 genes and see if you come up with 16 different kinds of gametes?

2. Two words: Punnett Square. In this case for a trihybrid cross:

[image: triple-het x triple-het cross found on Google Image]

3. That is a Bernoulli coin-flipping probability. If you are flipping a true coin three times in a row, how often will you get three heads in a row? 1/8? All the events are independent, right? what about the Punnett square? Does it give the same result somehow?

Here is the [answer](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/A-Trihybrid-Cross-Example-Using-Mendel%E2%80%99s-Sweet-Peas.pdf) worked out for you.